# Not able to read data through serial port

Tags: linux, serial-port, beagleboard

I am trying to read data on a serial port.

**My setup**

- OS: Ubuntu linux
- Device 1: [BeagleBoard](http://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoard)
- Device 2: My laptop

I am using a serial to usb converter.  On the BeagleBoard, the serial device is `ttyS2`.  On the laptop, it is `ttyUSB0`.

I did a simple thing to test the connection, I ran Minicom on both the machines. When I type something on BeagleBoard I receive data on laptop but it doesn't work the opposite way. What can be the reason?

The setting for serial port on both the devices are

- Baud rate: 115200
- Data size: 8
- Parity:N
- stop bit:1
- Hardware flow control : no

Comment: This question is more for superuser than stackoverflow.

Comment: True , i say , give some code or the program that you are using.

Comment: Output of `cat /proc/tty/driver/serial` at both ends woul be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your file permissions are too restrictive on your laptop? I had a similar problem on ubuntu, and solved it by changing the file permissions. You could test this by doing:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Note, these permissions will be reverted when you reset the connection. For a long tem solution you'll have to add yourself to the `dialout` group by editing `/etc/group`.

Comment: For a long term solution you should make udev set up an ACL entry for your user. Group-based permissions are so archaic (and often undesired, because they give you access to more stuff than you envisioned).